# Is there any GUI front end for sftp?

Tags: sftp

I know that one can connect to an SFTP server using, e.g., FileZilla or Nautilus, but then it is not possible to specify any additional parameters commonly accepted by sftp. To be specific, I need to adjust request queue length and read/write size (switches -R and -B; see [this thread on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/843691/speed-up-sftp-uploads-on-high-latency-network)), for which these packages do not have any form fields in the site/server setup dialog windows.

Therefore: is there any GUI front end for sftp with which I could use these two switches?

Thanks.

nvx

Comment: Doubt it; those 2 are arcane settings. Even doubt you will see it do anything substantial using command line. Tthat topic also explains why you do NOT see this in GUIs: https://serverfault.com/a/843864/229730 Same goes for commandline: just open 2 terminals :)

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I asked is that -- in my experience -- it _does_ make a difference when uploading data via a VDSL line. Without this customisation, PCs on the same LAN often fail to receive the response even to a simple DNS request while the upload is in progress. Well, it seems that I'll just have to continue using the terminal... ;)